# OutputCache Client side not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I am using MVC and OutputCache attribute for client side caching.

When I set OutputCache Location to Client what I expect to see is on the second and continues requests, action shouldn't be hit. OutputCache needs to send 302 response code if the time not exceed.
But on the real this isn't happen, when i refresh the page action is runnning. why outputCache doesn't send 302 response code and prevent action to be run.

```
   [OutputCache(Location=OutputCacheLocation.Client,Duration=60)]
    public ActionResult Text()
    {
        return Content("text");
    }
```

Comment: How are you refreshing? Are you by some chance hitting `Ctrl+F5` in your browser?

Comment: check this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592284/outputcache-location-client-does-not-appear-to-work

Comment: Yes I am also try with ctrl+f5, I know that browser will request file from server but server need to response 304 because of outputcache am I false