# JQuery load does not load from cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

On my controller

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 60, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Any)]
```

I have this attribute. In my view I have

```
<div id="hot-topics-replacement" url="@Url.Action("IndexPartial", "Topics")"></div>
```

And this is JQuery code

```
var url = $("#hot-topics-replacement").attr("url");
$("#hot-topics-replacement").load(url, function () { ResizeHotTopics(); });
```

It always makes a request to server. I was expecting at least it caches to browser (I am testing on Chrome) but it doesn't do it.

I don't know where is my mistake.

**EDIT SOLVED**
When I check Response Headers, I observed that between last modified date and expiration date there is just 10 seconds instead of 60. Now I made the `Cache Duration` 200 seconds and it works.

As far as I understood, there is something fishy about date times between server and client.

Comment: It makes the request to determine if the content has changed. If it gets a "notmodified" header in the response it will use the cached version.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mistake.

I suppose your problem is in your scenario how do you use this function. If you press F5 in browser client cache dissapears. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9597205/1849444).

Anyway i recommend you to check maby anywhere in your project client cache dissabled. Somethig like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // ...
    cache: false
    // ...
});
```