# OutputCache Not working on Page Load(Reload)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my project of MVC I am using OutputCache to cache page on both server and client side. Whenever I load page or reload page data is not coming from cache. Is there any explanation for this?

Controller:Main.cs

```
[OutputCache(Duration=3600)]
public ActionResult Main()
{
//some code
return View("~/Views/main.cshtml",DateTime.Now);
}
```

View:main.cshtml

```
@model DateTime
<h2>Hi</h2>
<h2>Hello</h2>
<h2>@Model</h2>
```

Comment: Please can you share your code

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Have you tried by adding `VaryByParam = "none"` ?

Comment: Are you getting issue in development machine means VS?

Comment: yes I tried VaryByParam="none" but it's also not working.

Comment: check with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592284/outputcache-location-client-does-not-appear-to-work

Comment: As I said I am caching page on both client and server so if F5 evicting the client cache there must be server copy but it is not.

Comment: @yajiv Can you try to create Viewbag variable and set it datetime.now value to check it in view layer